# Master Theorem change of variables with root other than 2

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I'm working on this:

$$T(n) = 12T(n^{1/3}) + \log(n)^{2}$$

Using change of variables, and substituting $m = \log n$, I get as far as:

$$S(m) = 12S(m/3) + m^{2}$$

I see how a square root would work but with a cube root I'm not sure that $\Theta(m \log m)$ makes sense since the convention seems to be that this means $\log_2 n$ and I'm not seeing how that accounts for a base $3$ $\log$.

Comment: You could substitute $k = \log_3(m)$ to get an equation of the form $R(k) = 12 R(k-1) + \dots$, which leaves you with a geometric series.

Comment: Note that $\log_a(x) = \log_b(x) / \log_b(a)$, so if $b$ and $a$ are constant (say $2$ and $3$), $\Theta(\log_a x) \equiv \Theta(\log_b x)$.

Comment: sorry not quite following you. i was expecting the next step to be something like $$S(m) = \Theta(m^{2} \log_3 m)$$ so that 1 of the 3 cases is found. i'm not sure how the geometric series would fit in. i can somewhat see how a change of base would be helpful but i'm also not seeing exactly how it works in this case. i'm learning this as i go, thanks for your patience

Comment: The base on a log is usually ignored in big-$O$ notation because $\log_a x$ and $\log_b x$ are related by a multiplicative constant for any bases $a$ and $b$, and these are exactly what the big-$O$ notation ignores. (This is what TMM's second comment is about.)

Comment: ok so if i understand you correctly, then what you're saying is that we use $\Theta(m^{2} \log m)$ here. or do we just use $\Theta(m \log m)$ since the constants are ignored. thanks for clarifying the above comment, i now understand what that was about. the only thing i'm not sure about is whether this is $m$ or $m^{2}$ as i noted above.

Comment: @stackuser: The constant can be ignored in the base of the logarithm, because $\log_b(x) = C \cdot \log_a(x)$, and by simple manipulation of the rules of $\Theta$, we know that $\Theta(f) = \Theta(C \cdot f)$. But the same does not apply to $x^2 \neq C \cdot x$, so $\Theta(m^2 \log m) \neq \Theta(m \log m)$.

Comment: what's slightly confusing is the answer below. this seems well written but i'm not sure that it agrees with disregarding the constant log bases. so it seems like your explanation leads to $\Theta (\log n \log \log n)$ since this follows from $m log m$ but the answer below seems very different and doesn't disregard the log bases. on a side note, i'd really like to study comp sci in the netherlands (university amsterdam), if i can only get a scholarship. looks like a nice place though. too hot here in florida.

Comment: Use Leighton's form of the Akra-Bazzi theorem ([Notes on Better Master Theorems for Divide-and-Conquerr Recurrences](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/252350.html))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n=3^m$ (that is, let $m=\log_3n$). Then by a change of variables, we have:
$$
T(3^m) = 12T((3^m)^{1/3}) + (\log(3^m))^{2} = 12T(3^{m/3}) + (m\log3)^{2} = 12T(3^{m/3}) + (\log3)^{2}m^2
$$
Renaming $S(m)=T(3^m)$ yields: $\boxed{S(m)=12S(m/3)+(\log3)^{2}m^2}$

Since $\log_3{12}>\log_3{9}=2$, it follows that $(\log3)^{2}m^2=O(n^{\log_3{12}-\epsilon})$ if  $0<\epsilon\le\log_3{12}-2$. Thus, by Case 1 of the Master Theorem, we have $\boxed{S(m)=\Theta(m^{\log_3{12}})}$. Changing variables back to the original recurrence yields:
$$
T(n)=T(3^m)=S(m)=\Theta(m^{\log_3{12}})=\Theta((\log_3n)^{\log_3{12}})=\boxed{\Theta((\log n)^{\log_3{12}})}
$$
Using the identity $x^{\log_b{y}}=y^{\log_b{x}}$, we can alternatively write this as:
$$
T(n)=\boxed{\Theta(12^{\log_3{\log n}})}
$$

Comment: thanks, not sure if you saw the comments above, but it seems to me that you didn't just disregard the constant log bases and let m = lg n. i'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Notice that $(3n)^2 = 9n^2 = \Theta(n^2)$, so we can disregard the $3$. However, we can NOT say that $2^{3n}=\Theta(2^n)$ because in fact $2^{3n}=(2^3)^n=8^n=\Theta(8^n)$. In general, constants can be dropped if it is in the base, but not if it is in the exponent.

Comment: brilliant. good explanation too. the only thing i don't see is what is happening with the base 'a' of the log. i'm trying to understand why that can be left as a variable. in the master theorem, it seems like in this case a=1, so i'm not sure why you don't just write 1 instead of a. and if a=1 then why write it all, the entire log expression is just 1 (1 raised to any power is still 1).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean. In my solution (when solving the recurrence for $S(m)$), I had $a=12, b=3$ and I had to compare $(\log{3})^2{m}^2$ with $m^{\log_b{a}}$. The base of the log is $b=3$, not $a$. The size of the font for the subscript can make it a bit hard to read.

Comment: ok i think i see. you have $b=3$ from $S(m/3)$ so that 3 is your base. the change of variables is really new for me (so is master theorem), so i sometimes look at the $T(n)$ instead of the $S(m)$.